# Use array element in closure

Tags: php, closures

PHP 5.3 added support for closures, and I was wondering if you can close over a specific array element instead of the entire array.

For example, you can do this:

```
$a = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
$f = function($b) use($a){
    echo $a[2].$b;
};
$f('!'); // echos "i!"
```

But is there a way to only close around `$a[2]`?  Something like this maybe:

```
$f = function($b) use($a[2] as $c){
    echo $c.$b;
};
```

This doesn't work, it gives:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ')'

Obviously, I could do this:

```
$c = $a[2];
$f = function($b) use($c){
    echo $c.$b;
};
```

But, I figured there had to be a better way than that.  So, is there any way to just close around a specific variable in an array?

Comment: It's not possible. If it were possible, it would be syntactic sugar more than anything.

Comment: @zi42: "Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commentators already mentioned: No.

At the moment `use` expects only a T_Variable ($var) or a Reference T_Variable (&$var). 
But there is a patch making the use of `as` possible like in your example. It can be found on [gist](https://gist.github.com/2367913).

Maybe this will be merged into master some time, so that it would be possible in a future release.

But i really don´t think this is a huge feature :-)

So you have to go with your alternate solution in the meantime.

Comment: Its 2020 now and it still doesn't seem to have been merged in PHP 7.4.9